# Cannot rename files in sub directories with rename-item in Shared Folder location on Synology

Tags: powershell, share, synology

I have several `.mkv` files on a Synology NAS in sub directories of a Shared Folder that have the following `.partial~` extension appended at the end.

I am trying to remove `.partial~` from the end of these files, and ignore all other files located within such as `.jpg`

Folder\File Structure Eg:

> \\NAS\SharedFolder\Subdirectory1\Subdirectory2\file.mkv.partial~
>
> \\NAS\SharedFolder\Subdirectory1\file.mkv.partial~
>
> \\NAS\SharedFolder\Subdirectory1\file.jpg

I have created the following powershell script `strippartialext.ps1` that works correctly when run on my Windows 10 PC from within Subdirectory1 or Subdirectory2:

> \\NAS\SharedFolder\Subdirectory1\strippartialext.ps1 [WORKS HERE]
>
> \\NAS\SharedFolder\Subdirectory1\Subdirectory2\strippartialext.ps1 [WORKS HERE]

It strips out everything below either (and into subdirectories below) but does not work when run from the top SharedFolder location:

> \\NAS\SharedFolder\strippartialext.ps1 [DOES NOT WORK HERE]

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace(".partial~","")}
```

I get the following errors when running the .ps1 file from the SharedFolder location:

> Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\NAS\sharedfolder\Sub Directory1\file.jpg' does not exist.
>   At \NAS\sharedfolder\strippartialext.ps1:1 char:36
>   + ... curse | % { Rename-Item -Path $*.PSPath -NewName $*.Name.replace(".pa ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

I would like to know how to get this file to run from the SharedFolder location as I would only have to run this script once to cover all of my files instead of hundred of times separately within each Sub directory Folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Rename-Item` cmdlet accepts piped input, so I'd try:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse "*.partial~" | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.replace(".partial~","")} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK remove hte `-WhatIf`

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, this script without the '-WhatIf' worked!